# How to extend a class array/ call class array attributes after extend a class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, class-attributes

for a larg-DB based dynamically-multiple-area-menu, I created a class MenuPoint:

```
class MenuPoint{
public int areaId;

public int preID;

public String name;
public String desc;

public String stepInImg = "bsp.img";
public String stepOutImg = "bsp.img";

public String detailedForm = "bsp.fxml";
public String detailedImg = "bsp.img";

public String [] additionalOptionForm = new String[0];
public String [] additionalOptionName = new String[0];
public String [] additionalOptionImg = new String[0];}
```

and initialised it as an 0-length array in my main class: `MenuController`
 `public MenuPoint [] menuItem = new MenuPoint[0];`

I use a API call to get my DB stored information by initialisation of MenuController.
I store the results by using the following code:

```
int dataStructlength = 12;
    String[] exampleApiResultKeys = new String[dataStructlength];
    exampleApiResultKeys[0] = "SITE_NUMBER";
    exampleApiResultKeys[1] = "SITE_DESC";
    exampleApiResultKeys[2] = "SITE_NUMBER_EXT";
    exampleApiResultKeys[3] = "CELL_NUMBER";
    exampleApiResultKeys[4] = "CELL_DESC";
    exampleApiResultKeys[5] = "CELL_TYPE";
    exampleApiResultKeys[6] = "MACHINE_GROUP_NUMBER";
    exampleApiResultKeys[7] = "MACHINE_GROUP_DESC";
    exampleApiResultKeys[8] = "MACHINE_GROUP_TYPE";
    exampleApiResultKeys[9] = "STATION_NUMBER";
    exampleApiResultKeys[10] = "STATION_DESC";
    exampleApiResultKeys[11] = "STATION_TYPE";

    exampleApiController.test_mdataGetMachineAssetStructure(exampleApiFilter, exampleApiResultKeys);

    for(int i = 0; exampleApiController.resultValues.value != null && i < exampleApiController.resultValues.value.length/12; i++)
    {
        boolean isUseless = false;
        for(int a = 0; a < dataStructlength; a ++)
            if(true == exampleApiController.resultValues.value[i*dataStructlength+a].trim().isEmpty())
                isUseless = true;

        if(!isUseless)
        {
        int preId= -1;
        if("M".equals(exampleApiController.resultValues.value[i*12+5]))
        {
            if(giveItemId(0, preId, exampleApiController.resultValues.value[i*12]) >= 0)
                preId = giveItemId(0, preId, exampleApiController.resultValues.value[i*12]);
            else
                preId = addMenuItem(0, preId, exampleApiController.resultValues.value[i*12], exampleApiController.resultValues.value[i*12+1], "bsp.form");
        }
        if("M".equals(exampleApiController.resultValues.value[i*12+5]))
        {
            if(giveItemId(1, preId, exampleApiController.resultValues.value[i*12+3]) >= 0)
                preId = giveItemId(0, preId, exampleApiController.resultValues.value[i*12+3]);
            else
                preId = addMenuItem(1, preId, exampleApiController.resultValues.value[i*12+3], exampleApiController.resultValues.value[i*12+4], "bsp.form");
        }
        if("M".equals(exampleApiController.resultValues.value[i*12+8]))
        {
            if(giveItemId(2, preId, exampleApiController.resultValues.value[i*12+6]) >= 0)
                preId = giveItemId(0, preId, exampleApiController.resultValues.value[i*12+6]);
            else
                preId = addMenuItem(2, preId, exampleApiController.resultValues.value[i*12+6], exampleApiController.resultValues.value[i*12+7], "bsp.form");
        }
        if("M".equals(exampleApiController.resultValues.value[i*12+11]))
        {
            if(giveItemId(3, preId, exampleApiController.resultValues.value[i*12+9]) >= 0)
                preId = giveItemId(0, preId, exampleApiController.resultValues.value[i*12+9]);
            else
                preId = addMenuItem(3, preId, exampleApiController.resultValues.value[i*12+9], exampleApiController.resultValues.value[i*12+10], "bsp.form");
        }
        }
```

giveItemId:

```
public int giveItemId(int areaId_temp, int preId_temp, String name_temp)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < menuItem.length; i++)
    {
        if(menuItem[i].areaId == areaId_temp && menuItem[i].name.equals(name_temp) &&  menuItem[i].preID == preId_temp)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

addMenuItem:

```
public int addMenuItem(int areaId_temp, int preId_temp, String name_temp, String desc_temp, String form_temp)
{
    Object newArray1 = Array.newInstance(menuItem.getClass().getComponentType(), Array.getLength(menuItem)+1);  // +1 Arrayfeld
    System.arraycopy(menuItem, 0, newArray1, 0, Array.getLength(menuItem));
    menuItem = (MenuPoint[]) newArray1; // expend but missing attributes

    menuItem[menuItem.length-1].areaId = areaId_temp;
    menuItem[menuItem.length-1].preID = preId_temp;
    menuItem[menuItem.length-1].name = name_temp;
    menuItem[menuItem.length-1].desc = desc_temp;
    menuItem[menuItem.length-1].detailedForm = form_temp;
    return menuItem.length-1;
}
```

I found out that menuItem dons´t carry any attributes after expending it.

Do I have to create "new" Instances of MenuPoint to make it work?
Is it even possible to expend a class-array without loosing attributes or their values? 
It shoud, because in the end menuItem is just a pointer-array, pointing on multiple workstorage-addresses, aren't it?

Thank you guys for any tips or better concept you can give me. (I know this class-concept is silly but I have no idea for a better one)
And please excuse my bad grammar.

Comment: Use a `List`. These automatically resize when you add items. Arrays are for when you know the exact number of items at construction time; and even then a `List` is often more convenient.

Comment: P.S.  Please use a spell check on your question before posting.

Comment: "I found out that menuItem..." How? Have you got some code to demonstrate  it?

Comment: Of curse a made an edit. Btw. I use example names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new array in method addMenuItem which is then populated with the members from the existing menuItem, but the element at index (new) length - 1 isn't initialized:

```
menuItem[menuItem.length-1] = new MenuPoint();
```

You should have gotten a NullPointerException when trying to set the fields.

All this usage of java.lang.reflect.Array is rather contrived. There are simpler ways to achieve this. Here is a simplified versio of addMenuItem

```
public int addMenuItem(int areaId, String name){
    MenuPoint[] newMenuItem = new MenuPoint[menuItem.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(menuItem, 0, newMenuITem, 0, menuItem.length);
    menuItem = newMenuItem;
    menuItem[menuItem.length-1] = new MenuPoint();
    menuItem[menuItem.length-1].areaId = areaId;
    menuItem[menuItem.length-1].name = name;
    return menuItem.length; // Why -1 ? 
}
```

But, above all, do use a `List<MenuPoint>`.

Comment: Ok sry ...
I correct it. 
But thanks to all of you ^^

Answer (score 1):

For the answer of your question `Do I have to create "new" Instances of MenuPoint to make it work?`

`Yes`

From your code snippets you need to initialize `MenuPoint` class object to store its values to the array `menuItem`.
Initialize your array element with below line

```
menuItem[menuItem.length-1] = new MenuPoint();
```

Place above line after copying your array by `menuItem = (MenuPoint[]) newArray1;`

Without initialization there is `NullPointerException` exception for setting values to null object.

There are some better ways to maintain list of object using [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) class.

To use ArrayList you need following code change

```
public List<MenuPoint> menuItem = new ArrayList<MenuPoint>; //Initialize list
```

Your Function will be

```
public int addMenuItem(int areaId_temp, int preId_temp, String name_temp, String desc_temp, String form_temp)
    {
        MenuPoint menuPoint = new MenuPoint();

        menuPoint.areaId = areaId_temp;
        menuPoint.preID = preId_temp;
        menuPoint.name = name_temp;
        menuPoint.desc = desc_temp;
        menuPoint.detailedForm = form_temp;
        menuItem.add(menuPoint);

        return menuItem.size()-1;
    }
```

I think this is easy than using reflection with array.

Comment: Thank you, of curse I have to do it like this ^^
But I think laune is right :)
I shoud use lists ^^